# JOIN 2 Tables get Unique values from 2 columns

Tags: t-sql, join

I have a (i think) complicated problem, and have no idea how to do that in SQL (the whole day). I have turned the logic around a couple of times, and always something is missing.

There is a join between 2 tables that hold different FK references to a 3rd table.

How to join those 2 tables, so i am sure that all FK combinations are presented, and all are unique?
I need to have the 2 FK columns in one, so i can later join to 3rd. nulls are possible. Group by not possible, since i need to know where the record is from (need Id_1 and Id_2 in the result)

here the sample code:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (Id int, CommonId int, FK_Id_1 int)
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (Id int,CommonId int, FK_Id_2 int)


INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (1,1,1)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (2,1,2)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (3,2,3)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (4,3,NULL)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (5,4,NULL)

INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES (11,1,1)
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES (12,2,2)
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES (13,2,3)
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES (14,4,5)

SELECT t1.Id as Id_1,t2.Id as Id_2, t1.CommonId, t1.FK_Id_1, t2.FK_Id_2,
COUNT(t1.FK_Id_1) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.FK_Id_1) AS T1_RANK,
COUNT(t2.FK_Id_2) OVER (PARTITION BY t2.FK_Id_2)AS T2_RANK
FROM @T1 t1 
 FULL JOIN @T2 t2 on t1.CommonId = t2.CommonId
ORDER BY CommonId
```

This query is returning this:

```
Id_1        Id_2        CommonId    FK_Id_1     FK_Id_2     T1_RANK     T2_RANK
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           11          1           1           1           1           2
2           11          1           2           1           1           2
3           12          2           3           2           2           1
3           13          2           3           3           2           1
4           NULL        3           NULL        NULL        0           0
5           14          4           NULL        5           0           1
```

and i need somehow to make it look like this:

```
Id_1        Id_2        CommonId    FK_Id
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           11          1           1
2           11          1           2
3           12          2           2
3           13          2           3
4           NULL        3           NULL
5           14          4           5
```

I did something like `SELECT COALESCE(FK_Id_1,FK_Id_2) AS FK_Id` but this is always selecting T1 with priority. I am thinking of some way to switch the priority depending of the duplicated values.

i have a ugly solution that looks like this, but am looking for a better ideas.

```
;WITH tmp as (
SELECT t1.Id as Id_1,t2.Id as Id_2, t1.CommonId, t1.FK_Id_1, t2.FK_Id_2,
COUNT(t1.FK_Id_1) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.FK_Id_1) AS T1_RANK,
COUNT(t2.FK_Id_2) OVER (PARTITION BY t2.FK_Id_2)AS T2_RANK
FROM @T1 t1 
FULL JOIN @T2 t2 on t1.CommonId = t2.CommonId)
SELECT Id_1, Id_2, CommonId, 
CASE 
    WHEN T1_RANK > T2_RANK THEN COALESCE(FK_Id_2,FK_Id_1)
    WHEN T2_RANK > T1_RANK THEN COALESCE(FK_Id_1,FK_Id_2)
END AS FK_Id
FROM tmp
ORDER BY CommonId
```

I don't know if i explained the whole situation correctly, i must join the tables, because i have other columns coming only from T1 and T2 ( can not UNION->DISTINCT - this will select also the NULLs)

Answer (score 0):

just pick the CommonId, and then full join to both tables.

**the query below matches 100% to your desired result.**

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CommonId FROM @T1
    UNION SELECT CommonId FROM @T2
)
SELECT t1.Id AS Id_1, t2.Id AS Id_2, cte.CommonId, ISNULL(t2.FK_Id_2, t1.FK_Id_1) AS FK_Id 
FROM cte
FULL OUTER JOIN @T1 t1 ON cte.CommonId = t1.CommonId
FULL OUTER JOIN @T2 t2 ON cte.CommonId = t2.CommonId
```

Beware that that the results of the FK_Id changes with the column order in the `ISNULL` in the predicate

`ISNULL(t2.FK_Id_2, t1.FK_Id_1)` is not the same as `ISNULL(t1.FK_Id_1, t2.FK_Id_2)`

**In my opinion this *alternative version* fits better your request, since it's taking both options of FK.**

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CommonId FROM @T1
    UNION SELECT CommonId FROM @T2
)
SELECT t1.Id AS Id_1, t2.Id AS Id_2, cte.CommonId, ISNULL(t2.FK_Id_2, t1.FK_Id_1) AS FK_Id--, cte.CommonId,   * 
FROM cte
FULL OUTER JOIN @T1 t1 ON cte.CommonId = t1.CommonId
FULL OUTER JOIN @T2 t2 ON cte.CommonId = t2.CommonId
UNION 
SELECT t1.Id AS Id_1, t2.Id AS Id_2, cte.CommonId, ISNULL(t1.FK_Id_1, t2.FK_Id_2) AS FK_Id--, cte.CommonId,   * 
FROM cte
FULL OUTER JOIN @T1 t1 ON cte.CommonId = t1.CommonId
FULL OUTER JOIN @T2 t2 ON cte.CommonId = t2.CommonId
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
The first query does not work in 100% of the cases. there should be no difference between T1 and T2. The sample data just gives all possible combinations for T1, but there should not be a priority of T2 over T1. the second script gives all possibilities, but i need only the unique ones, since this table has 3-4 column-pairs like this, and all combinations will be 2(n) for 1 group, with a lot of nulls.

Comment: @d.popov , so lets concentrate on the second script. can you please clarify: **1)** What do you mean by `unique ones`? Since I'm using `UNION` in the CTE and outside, duplicates are eliminated. **2)** can you please share more details on `since this table has 3-4 column-pairs like this`?